# Why does Visual Studio hog my other programs' hot keys?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, hotkeys

I have found, consistently, that if I use something like [Switcher](http://insentient.net/) (highly recommended), or [Toastify](http://toastify.codeplex.com/) (both are programs that rely on the use of global hot keys to work) that when Visual Studio 2008 has focus none of the hot keys for the other applications work.

Does anyone know why this might be and how to fix it?

Comment: Try going to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard.  Look for the hotkeys which you want to use, and check if their assignment is "Global" - if so, delete it, and if you need it, replace it by changing the "Use new shortcut in" to the proper use.

Answer (score 2):

I thought that in windows the currently active window, and then its parents always get first dibs at any UI event - so that it can handle them. VS handles so many key strokes there will likely be something  already hooked. See Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard like @breakthrough says.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that it is because Visual Studio was running in Administrator mode and therefore other programs with less privileges do not get a look in to the hot keys whilst it is in focus. If I run the other programs with administrator privileges also then it then Visual Studio no longer becomes a barrier.

To extend, the pattern is the same for any running programs: hotkeys from non-admin processes will not be caught if an admin-process has focus.